# Reading a file and appending to a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm running into troubles appending data into a dictionary.

data:

```
string integer 
string integer 
string integer 
string integer
```

the text file on notepad it looks like:

```
STRING 13STRING 4STRING 1STRING 4STRING 2STRING 7
```

Initially one of the strings were missing an integer, I just added one into the text file and saved it to first make sure I can append the info into a dictionary

code:

```
d = {}
file = open('data.txt','r')
for line in file:
    data = line.split()
    key, value = data[0], data[1]
    d[key] = value
print(d)
```

Comment: Are there new lines in the file. Furthermore what is not working? I do not see a problem immidiately? Do you get an error? Is the output wrong?

Comment: I get an IndexError: list index out of range on line 5. I believe the text file does have a new lines as when I copy and paste it into the IDE the info is formed as data within the original post.

Comment: So, all those strings and numbers are on the same line?

Comment: @skryt: but then your described format is not valid. Also not that if it is, the dictionary will look like `{'STRING':7}` since all "keys" are the same and it will thus keep the last value.

Comment: put a `print(data)` after line 4 and see what you get and whether it is what you expect.

Comment: sorry each individual string is unique, none of them are the same

Comment: So real data would help. I suspect one of your lines doesn't have an integer or there is no space between the string and integer, thus the index error. You should post runnable code so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RobertB Yeah, I got what I was hoping for ['string', 'value'] on a separate line, however I did get an extra dictionary out [] without any key or values in it. Which im assuming is why the error is getting thrown in there,

Comment: Probably a blank line in the input file?

Comment: Thats exactly what it was. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for the input described (STRING 13\nSTRING 4...), my guess is that you have an extra blank line in your data or have a string but forget the number. Try accounting for it:

```
d = {}
file = open('data.txt','r')
for line in file:
        data = line.split()
        if len(data) == 2:
            key, value = data[0], data[1]
            d[key] = value
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions to parse the file. This approach is very resilient to blank lines etc. Also, you are opening a file but not closing it, the best practice is to use "with" per the pattern below. Lastly, "file" is actually a thing in Python that you are clobbering with your variable name, I would avoid using that as a variable name:

```
import re
r = r'(.*?)\s*(\d*$)'
with open('data.txt','r') as f:
    d = dict([ re.match(r, line).groups() for line in f ])
print(d)
```

data.txt:

```
sjfklasdj1 231
sdf23 123
1ldfkjasdlfk 23

fasd
```

output:

```
{'': '', 'fasd': '', '1ldfkjasdlfk ': '23', 'sdf23 ': '123', 'sjfklasdj1 ': '231'}
```